# Android - Get List of Apps in Debug mode

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am trying to develop an android application where i have the following requirement. Is there any way through code, i can get the list of apps installed on devices in debug mode.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT - I tried the following code.

```
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
         List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        for (int i=0; i < packages.size(); i++)
            {
                if ((packages.get(i).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)
                {
                     //This is for System applications
                }
                else
                {

                    boolean isDebuggable =  (0 != ( getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE ) );

                    if((pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packages.get(i).packageName)!=null) && (isDebuggable = true) )                 
                    {
                        // Only For Apps with debug mode set true, this line should get executed 
                        // But this does not happens
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please define "in debug mode".

Comment: In android manifest xml, if android debuggable attribute is set true, then that app is set in android debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried various methods but as per my understanding, we cannot get the list of apps in debug mode seperately.

By using the flags, we can only get for the app which has this code and not other apps running on device.

Thanks anyways. If anybody has a different thought, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go,

```
Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( main, 0);
```

This should give you enough information in order to kick off an application.

Comment: Thanks but This did not work ... List contains all the apps not only the apps deployed in debug mode

Comment: My apologies, I thought you meant you wanted a list of apps from within an app that is in debug mode itself - not only "debug-mode apps".

Comment: You could use the taskAffinity string from activityInfo to get the package name, which you could then pass to getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo() in order to check FLAG_DEBUGGABLE

Comment: I can't really give out the answer. My above comment describes it well enough and if you follow the trail of documentation (ResolveInfo, ActivityInfo, PackageManager), you should be able to get it :)

Answer (score 0):

From Justin's answer

Kotlin

```
val allIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
val allApps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(allIntent, 0)
val debugApps = arrayListOf<ActivityInfo>()

allApps.forEach {
    val appInfo = (packageManager.getApplicationInfo(
        it.activityInfo.packageName,
        0
    ))
    if (0 != appInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) {
        debugApps.add(it.activityInfo)
    }
}

debugApps.forEach {
    Log.d("debugApps", it.packageName)
}
```

It is possible to get all the apps that are in debug mode.
In my device, I get all the apps that I've installed using Android studio.